# findstr: files to be searched have no line breaks

Tags: bash, findstr

I have several files that contain one long line. I want to search each file and count the number of occurrence of a string.
Bash script is my only option at this point.

`Findstr` searches per line. Given that there is only one line in each file that does not help me. I've done a bit of searching on this site and Googled it but can't come up with an answer.

Here is one sample I have tried.

This just essentially prints out each entire file:

```
findstr /C:Bob *.txt
```

What I would like to see is this?

```
File1.txt 14

File2.txt 27

File3.txt 136
```

etc....

Comment: Do you have the usual Posix command line utilities to go along with bash? (And is it really bash, rather than some Windows shell?) Or are you limited to Windows console commands?

Comment: @KateEvansBarrett : Note that your pattern *.txt, assuming that it is supposed to be a glob pattern, would denote **anything** in front of .txt, from the start of the file. You need to specify some rule, how the start of a string you are looking for would look like. Maybe as a regular expression. In this case, you could maybe indeed  use the regex operator from bash.

Comment: @rici - at this point, yes only console commands.

Comment: @user1934428 - the *.txt is intended to denote the file(s) I would like to search.  In this example, I am searching these files for the string "Bob".

Comment: So you basically want to know, how often a given string occurs in each file? I think in pure bash, this would be cumbersome. I would install something like Ruby (or maybe Perl) instead of bash for this type of task.

Comment: @KateEvansBarrett : Or, if you have the tools (I don't quite understand your comment that you have _only console commands_; does this mean you have the usual Posix programs installed, as rici asked, or not?), the solution using `grep`, presented by abhishek phukan in his answer, would do.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
find * -printf 'echo "$(grep -o "hello" %p | wc -l) %p";' | sh

output:
3 newfile
2 somefile
```

Alternate if above does not work

```
for var in `ls`;do echo $var; grep -o "hello" $var|wc -l;done

Output:
newfile
3
somefile
2
some.py
0
```

Assuming wc is not present as suggested in the comments for this answer, the below command can be used.

```
for var in `ls`;do echo $var;grep -o "hello" $var|grep -c "hello";done
```

Will provide the same output as last command

Comment: This assumes that the OP has `find` installed, which we don't know yet. As it stands for now, the question is to find a bash-only solution.

Comment: ah! ok. my bad. Let me search for an alternate

Comment: Well, and we don't necessarily have `wc` either.

Comment: wc should be inbuilt. Can you try the solution once and then let me know

Comment: `wc` is not a built-in bash command. See the bash man page. And I would write your loop as `for var in *`, as your solution would break if we have file names with spaces. For the same reason, `$var` should be quoted. And, `grep` is not an internal command either. For a bash-only solution, I would do a `fcont=$(<"$var")` to slurp the whole file into a variable and then use the `=~` operator to extract the parts related to the pattern I'm interested in.

Comment: @abhishekphukan These are the commands I've tried, using my example above.  All give me the error:
"The filename, directory name, or volume lable syntax is incorrect"

----find * -printf 'echo "$(grep -o "Bob" %p | wc -l) %p";' | sh


-----for var in `ls`;do echo $var;grep -o "Bob" $var|grep -c "Bob";done


-----for var in `ls`;do echo $var; grep -o "Bob" $var|wc -l;done

Comment: @KateEvansBarrett does ‘ls’ list the correct files ? And the above commands have to be executed in the same folder where the files are present